# variable of a object in an array

Tags: javascript, html

Would like to know if its possible to get a variable or function of an object that been pushed into an array 
want to add all the objects in the array where the function will get a string of the content to a web page

what i currently have:

```
recordjs
var recordArray = [];

function EmailRecord(name, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.getRecord = function() {
        return this.name+"|"+this.email;
    };
}   

function addRecord(){
    var n1 = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var e1 = document.getElementById("email").value
    var aRecord = new EmailRecord(n1,e1);
    recordArray.push(aRecord);


}

index.html
<label>Name: </label><input type="text" id="name"/>
<label>Email </label><input type="text" id="email"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Add a record" onclick="addRecord()"/>
<p id="p1"></p>
```

Comment: so you like to get the name of the variable or just the content?

Comment: want to use the content

Comment: Your question is pretty cryptic. Please provide us some code to give us a better understanding of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As per my udnerstanding you have one array and you want to join all the content of the array.

```
//If you have an array of name array1,
var array1=["value1","value2",....]
//To join all the elements, use below line
var allValues = array1.join();
```

Now allValues will contain "value1 value2 ..."